# which host will reply to the ping?

Tags: nat, ping

suppose having a LAN which contains :

- FTP server (10.0.0.1)
- HTTP server (10.0.0.2)
- SSH server (10.0.0.3)

the LAN use NAT overloading and it has a single public IP (1.2.3.4), now if I `ping` on 1.2.3.4 which server will reply ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Neither.

"Overload", or [Dynamic PAT](http://www.practicalnetworking.net/series/nat/dynamic-pat/), is [unidirectional](http://www.practicalnetworking.net/series/nat/dynamic-pat/#unidirectional). The connection will [only work if the Inside hosts initiate the connection](http://www.practicalnetworking.net/series/nat/dynamic-pat/#inbound-connection).

If you ping *from* the Internal hosts, an entry in the connection table will allow the response back through.

If you ping from *an external host*, there will be no entry in the connection table, and no way for the NAT device to know what internal host was the intended recipient... so the result:  the packet is dropped.

Comment: do you mean that the server should have his own public ip so we could ping on it ?
or in other words; all web servers in which we can ping are not using PAT ?

Comment: From a learning perspective, correct. In reality, however, most web-servers you are making requests to are sitting behind a Load Balancer that is doing the "Dynamic PAT" (among other things) so that many internal web servers can share a single public IP address. Often, in those cases, the Load Balancer itself is "smart enough" to simply respond to ping requests as opposed to trying to forward it to a server.